# How can you restore a password in MultiBit if you are given the wallet words BEFORE you even enter a password?

Tags: wallet, multibit, passphrase, wallet-security

How is it possible to recover a wallet password when the wallet words are provided before you even enter the password?

https://multibit.org/en/help/hd0.1/restore-password.html

> #### Restore password
>
> If you forget your wallet password, then you can restore your password from your wallet words.

Comment: You don't need to start a new question: make a comment at your other post

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie This is a different question! One questions asks how to restore a wallet from a random file location, and this question asks how it is possible to recover a password from a wallet using only wallet words when the password is given after the wallet words are generated. How can your reading comprehension be so dismal?

Comment: @Chloe Please assume good faith on behalf of other users, and don't call them names. See http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice, rules 1 and 2. There is a good-faith interpretation of Wizard of Ozzie's comment, which is that he disagrees with you about how similar the two questions are.

Comment: @Chloe Settle down, it says *possible* duplicate. My reading comprehension was based on two very similar threads created very close in time to each other. I didn't shut the thread; just wanted clarification, which you've now given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a copy of the password stored encrypted with an AES key derived from the wallet words.

Thus if you forget your password and still have a copy of your wallet you can use your wallet words to recover your password.

Comment: So the password is stored twice? Once encrypted with wallet words, and another time hashed for normal use? Then how can you change your password? Does that mean the wallet words are also stored unencrypted in your wallet?

Comment: If you change the password some backups are updated to reflect the change as well. See https://multibit.org/en/help/hd0.1/change-password.html for details.