# How MultiBit stores password

Tags: multibit, encryption, multibit-hd

I'm curious to understand how MultiBit stores my password.

The fact is: I can restore the password by using the 12 words. From [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/38951) it seems tha the AES key to encrypt the password is derived from the 12 words (probably viceversa, the 12 words are derived from the key). Thus:

- is the password stored twice? or better: (i) is the password store salted (for when i do the login, they probably check against a salt), and (ii) is it also stored encrypted with the key related to the 12 words?
- how are these 12 words generated and how is the key generated for the AES?